# Null Pointer após try catch

Tags: java

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/AdicionaContato")
public class AdicionaContatoServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //busca o writter
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        //busca parametros
        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");
        String endereco = request.getParameter("endereco");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String dataEmTexto = request.getParameter("DataNascimento");

        //Converter data
        Calendar dataNascimento = null;
        try {
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dataEmTexto);
            dataNascimento = Calendar.getInstance();
            dataNascimento.setTime(date);
        } catch (ParseException e){
            out.println("Erro na conversão da data");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Após usar o `SimpleDataFormat` e setar a data com `getInstance` / `setTime` não era para a mesma estar populada ?

Minha página HTML que faz o subbmit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Adicionar contatos</title>
</head>
<body>
      <form action="AdicionaContato">
       Nome : <input type="text" name="nome" /> <br/>
       E-mail: <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
       Endereço: <input type="text" name="endereco" /> <br/>
       Data Nascimento: <input type="text" name="dataNascimento" /><br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Gravar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `name` do input da data de nascimento está diferente do nome utilizado no `getParameter(String)`.

Um está assim: `dataNascimento`, e o outro está assim: `DataNascimento` o `getParameter` é *Case Sensitive*.

Verifique se essa não é a causa do problema.

Comment: era isso mesmo, obrigado